# Synchronization of two Artifactories

Tags: maven, jenkins, hudson, cloud-foundry, artifactory

I have two Artifactory repos for maven in two distinct places and domains, but I need to synchronize it for that, when to deploy in one of theirs the other must have their information.

I don't know if Jenkins, Hudson, or TeamCity can help me in this work and how I can do it or the cloud workspace like cloudfoundry an cloudbees can help me. I was reading something like these [here](http://blog.cloudfoundry.com/2013/02/28/continuous-integration-to-cloud-foundry-com-using-jenkins-in-the-cloud/)

Comment: AFAIK Artifactory has some kind of synchronization in it which can be used for such thing. But the question why do you have separate areas using the same. Furthermore you can define the area A where you deploy as a remote repository in area B within artifactory.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to achieve this.

1. using cluster feature for sync method in artifactory, this will sync. all repo including your maven sites http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Clustering+Artifactory, surely it depends the relation of your two artifactory
2. using maven command, why not use maven deploy commands to deploy two maven sites every time
3. create one jenkins job to sync the maven repo when one is updated
4. using `rsync` command to sync the repos (directory) in back directly

Answer (score 2):

The answer is so obvious, I am a bit surprised the other authors use phrases like "some kind of synchronization" and " cluster feature for sync". Artifactory has full push/pull 2-way (optionally event-based) replication. Period. [Just read the manual](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Replication).

Comment: I am a bit skeptical on this: the manual seems suggesting replicating one repo to another.  However what OP ask for is, he want 2 fully functional repo, for which things will be synchronized between them.  The difference is, for replication, assume A replicate to B, if someone deploy an artifact in A, you will see it in B.  However when someone deploy in B, you will not see it in A.  Can the replication of Artifactory be done in bi-direction?

Comment: Although I too think it is not really necessary to make things that complex: I would also prefer just have a central repo, for which different team will deploy artifacts to, and setup "readonly" replicated repo in different location.

Comment: In Artifactory in A and B pair one is always a remote repository, while the other is always local, which makes it impossible to deploy to both A and B (since one of them is remote).